# aws s3 bucket level key expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I understand that kms can generate a short lives bucket level key which then gives s3 data keys to encrypt new objects , reducing the call to kms significantly.
However , my confusion was since the objects are now encrypted using the data key generated by the bucket level key, what happens if the bucket key is removed (as mentioned it is short lived) and gets replaced by another key or what if its removed and now the request has to go to KMS directly. Does KMS know how to decrypt these data keys ?

"Does kms know how to decrypt the data key thats generated by bucket level kms key"?
reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-key.html#bucket-key-overview

Comment: From my reading of that page, the "short-lived bucket-level key" is actually the long-lived Bucket Key but it is 'cached' locally for a short period.`